# What cause SQL slowdown in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python, dbeaver

My problem is that when I run project or debug, the first query run so fast in about < 1s, but when it comes to run second query, it costs more than 30s. I'm so confused about it. I have already ran it in DB editor, both of them run so fast, doesn't have any problem. First look, two queries is quite similar so I do not know why caused it.
By the way sometimes I debug, it pop up a **red notice** in the left  `debug and run` tab, but I cannot get screen shot of this. It just appear once or twice .

[This is screen shot of sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpuA.png)

**query 1:** `rows = db.select("SELECT recruiter_id FROM linkedin.candidates WHERE recruiter_id in (" + ",".join(recruiter_ids) + ")")`

**query 2:** `rows = db.select("select c.recruiter_id, c.updated from linkedin.candidates c where c.recruiter_id in (" + ",".join(duplicates_rid) + ")")`

**This is my code**

```
if recruiter_ids:
        print("Creating connection to MySQL in recruiter 12")
        rows = db.select("SELECT recruiter_id FROM linkedin.candidates WHERE recruiter_id in (" + ",".join(recruiter_ids) + ")")
        db_recruiter_ids = [r['recruiter_id'] for r in rows] + [get_recruiter_id(url) for url in duplicates]
        print("Recruiter ids in database:", len(db_recruiter_ids), db_recruiter_ids[:5])
        duplicates = [url for url in profile_urls if any(get_recruiter_id(url) == rid for rid in db_recruiter_ids)]
        duplicates_rid = [ get_recruiter_id(url) for url in duplicates]
        if duplicates_rid:
            rows = db.select("select c.recruiter_id, c.updated from linkedin.candidates c where c.recruiter_id in (" + ", ".join(duplicates_rid) + ")")
            #rows = db.select("select c.recruiter_id, c.updated from linkedin.candidates c where c.recruiter_id in {}".format(tuple(duplicates_rid)))
            rows = [r['recruiter_id'] for r in rows if r['updated'] < datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)]
            old_resumes = [url for url in profile_urls if any(get_recruiter_id(url) == r for r in rows)]

        profile_urls = [url for url in profile_urls if not any(get_recruiter_id(url) == rid for rid in db_recruiter_ids)]
        print("Found duplicates in list:", len(duplicates), duplicates[:3])
        if db_recruiter_ids:
            tag_candidate_by_recruiter_id(db, db_recruiter_ids, project_id, tracker_id)
```

Thank you guy so much !!

Comment: I don't think this is a python or sql related problem, maybe the timeout comes from get_recruiter_id(id).  By the way, don't post image with code, use code block instead

Comment: How many items in each IN list?

Comment: It's 1 but I found the problem, it's caused by there is no index for `updated` field in my DB, and there are more than 450.000 records. So it takes so long.